# Database design to manage user meetings

Tags: database, database-design

I have an existing database, with a bunch of users. These users will be split among two types, which we will call groups A and B. I need to make a system where group A can schedule meetings with a person in group B, at 20 specific time slots. To do this the way I want, I need:

- A way to pull a list of all users in group B and who they are meeting with at slot X, including users who don't have a meeting at the time being marked as NULL or similar. Alternatively (and, frankly, preferably), this could be an array of all slots for all users in group B.
- A way to pull up a full schedule for a given user, whether in group a or group B

I can't think of a decent way to structure a database to make these look-ups easy. Any Ideas?

Comment: please refine your explanation on the MEETING entity. Will a meeting be a "person-from-A"-"person-from B"? or will it be more like "person-from-A"-"group of people from B" ?

Comment: Edited. One on One meetings. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably have a table  for Users with a type filed... (A or B).  A "meeting slot" to define the specific meeting times.  A meeting table that has UserWhoScheduled (not necessary), "meeting slot", and MeetingID.  A User_meeting table to link users to meetings.

The look ups would be fairly simple.

Comment: Meeting slot would be its own table?

Comment: well if they were defined meeting slots...sure... but it would essentially be a "lookup" table and could be dropped.  It just allows you to enforce those as the only allowable times to schedule a meeting.  Otherwise people could use any timeslot.  Of course you could enforce those rules in your app... But by doing it in the database and not giving rights to that table to the end users the DB would enforce the data rule as well.